# How to select yr from timestamp and echo it

Tags: php, mysql

When i try mysql using heidi the values i need is posted but when i try to use it it doesnt echo anything

```
        $value = mysql_query("SELECT max(student_id) AS id FROM student");
        $qryResultArray = mysql_fetch_array($value);
        $student_id = $qryResultArray['id'];

        $result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_enrolled, '%Y') AS yr,
        DATE_FORMAT(date_enrolled, '%m') AS mth
        FROM student_course WHERE id=$student_id");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $yr = $row['yr'];
        $mth = $row['mth'];

        //when i echo the statement nothing is echoed
        echo "year ".$yr."<br>";
        echo "mth ".$mth."<br>";
```

Comment: how is date_enrolled stored in you database?, can you show me a sample?

Comment: date_enrolled is stored as timestamp
2014-02-25 23:41:31

Comment: Thanks...now please read my answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use one query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT YEAR(date_enrolled) AS yr,
    DATE_FORMAT(date_enrolled, '%m') AS mth
    FROM student_course WHERE id=(SELECT max(student_id) AS id FROM student)");
```

Update:

```
    $value = mysql_query("SELECT max(student_id) AS id FROM student");
    $qryResultArray = mysql_fetch_array($value);
    $student_id = $qryResultArray['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT YEAR(date_enrolled) AS yr,
    MONTH(date_enrolled) AS mth
    FROM student_course WHERE id= ".$student_id."");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $yr = $row['yr'];
    $mth = $row['mth'];

    //when i echo the statement nothing is echoed
    echo "year ".$yr."<br>";
    echo "mth ".$mth."<br>";
```

Comment: the 1st query is used for other INSERT statements. so having to qry is a must for me.

the 1st qry is used to get the auto increment id from student and then that id is used to insert to student_course table..

Comment: it still is not working.. but when i tried to substitute $student_id with a real number like 20 it works fine.. i tried adding ''  to it and still doesnt work.. im using $student_id on diff INSERT statements and its working fine..

eg:
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO character_reference (student_id, cr_name, cr_occ, cr_address)
     VALUES($student_id,'$cr_name2','$cr_occ2','$cr_address2')") or die (mysql_error());

and when i echo $student_id theres a value which is echoed.. do i need to parse it or something for it to be able to work for mysql?

Comment: thanks its working fine now...     $result = mysql_query("SELECT YEAR(date_enrolled) AS yr,
    MONTH(date_enrolled) AS mth
    FROM student_course WHERE id='$student_id'");